# Implementing Round Robin insertions to oracle rac db with the help of sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

Problem
My system inserts records to oracle rac DB at a rate of 600tps. During the insertion-procedure-call each record is assigned a sequence, so that each record should get distributed among 20 different batch ids (implementation of a round robin mechanism).
Following is the step for selecting batch
1) A record comes. Assigns nextValue from a sequence. 
2) Do MOD(sequence,20). It gives values from 0 to 19.

Issue:
3 records comes to DB simultaneously and hits 3 different nodes in RAC
Comes out with sequences 2,102,1002.
MOD for all happens to be same.
All try to get into the same batch.

Round Robin fails here.

Please help to resolve the issue.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: This needs a bit more setup info. How many instances? are services in use? Can the 'intert-proc-call' be separated in a dedicated service, running on 1 instance?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the implementation of Sequences on RAC. When a node is first asked for the next value of a sequence it get a bunch of them (e.g. 100 to 119) and then hands them out until it needs a new lot, when it gets another bunch (160 - 179). While Node 1 is handing out 100 then 101, Node 2 will be handing out 121, 122 etc etc.

The size of the 'bunch' is controlled by as I remember the Cache size defined on a Sequence. If you set a cache size of 0, then you will get no caching, and the sequences will be handed out sequentially. However, doing that will involve the Nodes is management overhead while they work out what the next one actually is, and with 600tps this might not be a good idea: you'd have to try it and see,